# Can we use different oracles for each (extended) Grover iteration?

Tags: grovers-algorithm

Within the context of Grover's algorithm,  if there are  $N/4$  elements marked instead of just one ($N = 2^n$) , if we run one iteration of Grover's algorithm (one phase inversion and one inversion about the mean ) and then measure, the probability that we see a marked element is 1 (simple calculation).

I propose the following extension.

The extension of Grover's algorithm.

First iteration.  We use an oracle that marks  $2^{n-2} - 1$ elements (chosen at random or otherwise) plus the element x* that we are interested in.  We run one iteration of Grover and we end up with a superposition of $2^{n-2}$ marked states including  x*.

Second iteration.  We use another oracle that marks  $2^{n-4}-1$  elements (from the  $2^{n-2}-1$  above) and x*. We run another Grover iteration and we end up with a superposition of $2^{n-4}$  marked states including x*.

And so on..........

At the k-th step we use an oracle that marks $ 2^{n-2k}-1$  elements and x* and we end up with a superposition of 
$2^{n-2k}$  marked states, including x*.

We continue this process for about  O(log N ) = O(n) steps. The difference is that at each iteration we use a different oracle.

At the end, when we measure we will find x* with high probability.

If correct (big IF here ) this would be an exponential speedup compared to Grover.

Question.  What am I missing  here? Is implementation possible?

Comment: Well, Grover's already operates in $O(\sqrt{N})$, so it's doubtful that there would be an exponential speedup. I also believe Grover's is asymptotically optimal... [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0810.3647.pdf) might help. (If you want further community look over, it'd be helpful to have a description how this would yield speedups, so naming the states step-by-step could help)

Comment: Note that this is not exactly Grover's algorithm,  it's an extension of Grover's algorithm.  This answer is interesting:  https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/38551/18017   It seems to allow different oracles for each step.

Comment: I think that article isn't as relevant, as it's talking about the explicit circuit construction of the marking oracle. I thought you were asking about the asymptotic runtime of Grover's with a modified oracle?

Comment: In the original Grover's algorithm the oracle is called once , then it's all about  phase inversion and  inversion about the mean, itetatively,  and it can be proved optimal.  I am talking about a modification of Grover's algorithm where at each step you use a different oracle,  it seems possible to implement.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to take advantage of the fact that if N/4 elements in the database are marked , then the output is a superposition of only marked elements (can be easily verified by calculation). At later stages if the input is a superposition of K states and K/4 states are marked,  then the output is a superposition of only marked states. I am trying to decrease the number  of marked states at every steps   but making sure that the state that I am reallly/actually  looking for  x* is  always included in this set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What am I missing  here? Is implementation possible?

The problem with this idea is that the diffusion operation you use is supposed to match the initial state of the search. If your initial state is $|v\rangle$ then your diffusion operation is $I - 2|v\rangle\langle v|$. This operation is only cheap to implement when $|v\rangle$ is simple. For example, typically $|v\rangle$ would be $|+\rangle^{\otimes n}$ since you can implement $I - 2|+\rangle^{\otimes n}\langle +|^{\otimes n}$ using a multi-controlled NOT with some Hadamards around it.

When you switch oracles halfway through your search, the initial state for the second half of the search is the superposition of classical states meeting the oracle from the first half: $\sum_{k | P_1(k)} |k\rangle$. The problem is that it is not cheap to implement $I - 2\sum_{k | P_1(k)} |k\rangle\langle k|$. You will find that each oracle call during the second half of the search is as expensive as the whole first half of the search.

Basically, you're right that the *number* of oracles calls is going to decrease exponentially as the algorithm progresses but the *cost of each call* is going up exponentially. You end up not getting any benefit.

Comment: I understand that the cost of each call is going up but I have trouble understanding the exponential increase in complexity.  I suspect that if the complexity of the initial states increases exponentially then the cost of the implementation of the diffusion operator would follow the same trend. In our case though the initial states are still just uniform superpositions of marked states (not all, a restricted/decreasing  number of  marked states ) from the previous iteration. Feedback appreciated @CraigGidney

Comment: And the way we choose a quarter of the states (including x*) from the currently active states, to be marked at the next iteration would follow a simple predefined algorithm. In other words, from an algorithmic perspective   I don't see why the complexity should scale  exponentially here. Considering your expertise and experience,  I don't argue against your answer,  I just don't get the exponential scaling argument  but I have no doubt that it would have to be a complex implementation.

Comment: @CristianDumitrescu Try to implement the invert-superposition-of-marked-elements and you'll see it more clearly.

Comment: For phase inversion of a superposition of marked states we just use some Control - Z gates using as controls some ancillary qubits with certain values (at each step) that reflect the algorithm that we use to select a quarter of the active states to be marked at the next iteration. This selection process needs at most O(1) gates at each step (apart from phase inversion cost ).

Comment: For the inversion about the mean, that's when we need to invert the superposition of marked states (basically revert the unitary gates from all previous  steps ), use Hadamard on n qubits, rebuild , and so on. I estimate at most a quadratic number of gates necessary, at each step. So inversion about the mean  needs at most $O(n^2)$  gates at each step. 


In total (to run $O(n)$ iterations) at most $O(n^3)$ gates are sufficient.  We might get away with $O(n^2)$ actually,  but let's be safe.

Comment: This is not an exponential cost. For a thousand qubits you would need a quantum circuit with a  million elementary gates (for quadratic cost ) or a billion (for cubic), that's a small price to pay in order to efficiently solve all NP complete problems of practical interest. That cannot be done with Grover unless you are willing to wait billions of years in order to get some answers.


Please let me know if my estimation is incorrect  @CraigGidney  BTW ,  I also  found your answer from 2017  to another question quite interesting. 

https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/38551/18017

Comment: @CristianDumitrescu Why do you think you only need $O(n^3)$ gates to do the inversion about the mean of the marked states? You didn't justify that number, you just said you estimated it. Actually write down the circuit you think will work and test it in a simulator.

Comment: I was just thinking about that. So that's where you think the cost jumps to exponential.  Inversion about the mean is the same as a reflection about the uniform superpositin of all  states. If I have to revert everything up to this point, then yes the cost doubles at every step, but I thought there was  a shortcut based on the fact that at each step only a finite number of gates select the K/4 marked states from the currently K active states (and we can control this selection process in detail).

Comment: Therefore deconstructing it (reverting the superposition of marked states ) should be easy. Thanks for the feedback  @CraigGidney  I need more time to think about this. Any helpful hints would be appreciated.

Comment: I currently take Professor Vazirani 's course on quantum computation from Berkeley,  on edX. The problem with which I started my question here is problem 6 from assignment 6 (easy calculation). The way to apply this result in order to extend Grover (the rest of my question),  that's my idea (good or bad). I  am only a beginner in this field, and for me it's a hobby.  I never used a quantum simulator , so I could be mistaken, you're probably right and the cost (in the number of necessary gates) could be exponential.  I just think that this idea deserves deeper  investigation.

Comment: Inversion about the mean is the same as a reflection with respect to the uniform superpositin of all states. In very high dimensional spaces this reflection is uniquely determined by a lot of parameters. If the vectors involved are not simple (and if we  cannot map this reflection in a low dimensional subspace) we don't have enough information in a polynomial number of gates in order to uniquely determine this reflection.  Got it, you are definitely correct  @CraigGidney , my idea doesn't work. I'm trying to see whether approximations could work (probably not) https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.02466

Comment: Once again,  thank you for your help.

Comment: I have a question about @CraigGidney 's explanation. He says the diffusion operation has to match the initial state - I broadly see this and understand it to mean that the diffusion operation prepares the initial state from |0> (cf Amplitude Amplification). 
Q: After one iteration of Grover's algorithm we have a state that is no longer the equal superposition state. This state is still a viable starting state for Grover's algorithm (it would use one less iteration, as one iteration is baked in). But it doesn't "match" the diffusion operation in the sense above. How to resolve this paradox?

Answer (score 0):

See this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GliOLKa_EFo&list=PL74Rel4IAsETUwZS_Se_P-fSEyEVQwni7&index=54) here professor Vazirani explains why you cannot have less than `sqrt(N)` steps if you want at least a constant probability.

Comment: Watch carefully what Professor Vazirani says between time:4:18 to time:4:40. That's what I am doing here, designing efficient oracles.

Comment: Unfortunately it  doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah that's unfortunate but don't worry keep going. Maybe next-time you'll succeed. :)